# Compare columns in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below scenario,a unique combination of DEAL_ID and CUST_NUM can have different CUST_IDs..

With the below query I can manually see that..

```
SELECT DEAL_ID,CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DEAL_ID ORDER BY DEAL_ID) RID FROM TABLE_A;
```

Scenario 1: with same CUST_ID

```
DEAL_ID   CUST_NUM  CUST_ID    RID 
10002804    609793    0229      1   
10002804    609793    0229      2   
10002804    609793    0229      3   
10002804    609793    0229      4   
10002804    609793    0229      5
```

Scenario 2: with different CUST_ID

```
DEAL_ID   CUST_NUM  CUST_ID    RID
10002804    609793     6221     1
10002804    609793     0229     2
10002804    609793     0229     3
10002804    609793     6221     4
10002804    609793     0229     5
```

I want to compare the CUST_ID column values for the combination of DEAL_ID and CUST_NUM with the help of RID.
how can I do that?

I want to see the result set look like..

```
DEAL_ID   CUST_NUM  CUST_ID  RID   COMPARE
10002804    609793    0229      1   SAME
10002804    609793    0229      2   SAME
10002804    609793    0229      3   SAME
10002804    609793    0229      4   SAME
10002804    609793    0229      5   SAME


DEAL_ID   CUST_NUM  CUST_ID  RID    COMPARE 
10002804    609793     6221     1   NOT SAME
10002804    609793     0229     2   NOT SAME
10002804    609793     0229     3   NOT SAME
10002804    609793     6221     4   NOT SAME
10002804    609793     0229     5   NOT SAME
```

Comment: What are you actually comparing? What qualities make the results 'same' and 'not same'? In that result set, it looks to me like RID 2, 3, and 5 should be equivalent.

Comment: Imagine you "union all" these rows in one table. Would we have to process them as separate groups, or the result would just be "NOT SAME"?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - Basically, if all CUST_ID's are same for DEAL_ID and CUST_NUM..I want to put the compare result as SAME..if not NOT SAME..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46723/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB
    ("DEAL_ID" int, "CUST_NUM" int, "CUST_ID" int, "RID" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (10002804, 609793, 6221, 1)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (10002804, 609793, 0229, 2)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (10002804, 609793, 0229, 3)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (10002804, 609793, 6221, 4)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (10002804, 609793, 0229, 5)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (100028041, 609793, 0229, 1)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (100028041, 609793, 0229, 2)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (100028041, 609793, 0229, 3)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (100028041, 609793, 0229, 4)
    INTO TAB ("DEAL_ID", "CUST_NUM", "CUST_ID", "RID")
         VALUES (100028041, 609793, 0229, 5)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select deal_id, cust_num, cust_id,
decode(
  count(distinct cust_id) 
  over (partition by deal_id, cust_num), 
  1, 'SAME', 
  'NOT SAME') same
from tab
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46723/3/0)**:

```
|   DEAL_ID | CUST_NUM | CUST_ID |     SAME |
|-----------|----------|---------|----------|
|  10002804 |   609793 |     229 | NOT SAME |
|  10002804 |   609793 |     229 | NOT SAME |
|  10002804 |   609793 |     229 | NOT SAME |
|  10002804 |   609793 |    6221 | NOT SAME |
|  10002804 |   609793 |    6221 | NOT SAME |
| 100028041 |   609793 |     229 |     SAME |
| 100028041 |   609793 |     229 |     SAME |
| 100028041 |   609793 |     229 |     SAME |
| 100028041 |   609793 |     229 |     SAME |
| 100028041 |   609793 |     229 |     SAME |
```